# Eigenvalue estimate of a Neumann-like Laplacian in a Lipschitz domain

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, eigenvalues

I have read quite some references on the smallest (for Dirichlet) and second smallest eigenvalues for the following Neumann eigenvalue problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = \lambda u,\;\text{ in } \Omega,
\\[4pt]
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Notice for above problem, its eigenpairs also serve as the eigenpair for the following eigenvalue problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = \lambda u,\;\text{ in } \Omega,
\\[4pt]
\displaystyle \int_{\Omega} u = 0.
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$
I am curious if there is any dedicated literature on the estimate of the smallest eigenvalue of problem (1). Or even the following more general eigenvalue problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = \lambda u,\;\text{ in } \Omega,
\\[4pt]
\displaystyle \int_{\Omega_1} u = 0, \; \text{ where }\Omega_1\subset \Omega, \;\mathrm{meas}(\Omega_1) >0.
\end{cases}
\tag{1*}
$$

Comment: These operators are not self-adjoint, so perhaps the eigenvalues won't be real.